# Copy Active sheet of all workbooks in a folder to a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have the following code to copy all worksheets of all workbooks in a given folder to a single workbook. I need to modify this code to copy only the active sheet on all workbooks (now it copies all the sheets). Can you help me with this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineFiles()

Dim Path            As String
Dim FileName        As String
Dim Wkb             As Workbook
Dim WS              As Worksheet

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "C:\" 'Change as needed
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
            WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next WS
        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This way you can do what you want:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineFiles()

Dim Path            As String
Dim FileName        As String
Dim Wkb             As Workbook
Dim WS              As Worksheet

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "C:\" 'Change as needed
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)

        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        'For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
        '    WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        'Next WS
        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note:

When you open the workbook, you go over all the sheets with the `FOR LOOP`, but you only need to copy the `ActiveSheet` then (as you said) you only need to copy to the new `Wrokbook`

Comment: i did, it says i need to get 15 points to display it publicly. thanks again!